# Connection from Excel VBA to Oracle DB using ADODB no longer works

Tags: excel, oracle, adodb

I have installed the Oracle 32 bit OLE DB provider (32-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC)).
I have only one Oracle client on my machine (Windows 10 64 bit).
My environment variables are OK.

What is very strange is that this setting used to work fine up to now (for smth like 5 years) and quite suddenly I got the error :

```
Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed
```

In my connection string I had :

```
Provider=Oracle Provider for OLE DB (equivalent to Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle)
```

Then when I changed the provider to Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle (equivalent to MSDAORA), I got the error

```
Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01019
```

I have tried many different connection strings, re-installing client, rebooting, changing env variables etc. Nothing worked.
I now believed it may be due to some Windows updates.
It's really killing me because it makes obsolete all the devs I've done on Excel using ADODB objects... anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the ODAC components were not properly installed.

- I first uninstalled the format ODAC products by using the uninstall.bat file with command all (see ODAC help)
- I the removed all env variables linked to Oracle (including in PATH) for sys user and usual user.
- Then I reinstalled using the latest version of ODAC (which is quite old btw) and following rigorously the process describe in the help file. Both connection string worked after a reboot.

One of the key thing was to add the bin path to the PATH env variable.
So for example if your ODAC components are installed in c:\oracle you have to add both c:\oracle AND c:\oracle\bin dirs in the PATH variable so that it works properly.

The mystery is that it has been working for years without this bin dir in the PATH and that it suddenly stopped working (but sometimes it worked randomly !). As said before, I think it may be due to some update packages that changed the way Windows consider env variables.

Cheers,

Paul